# Javascript - Why getElementById doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

It works if I use:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('download1').onclick = function() {
        window.location.href="https://youtube.com";
    };
</script>
```

But if I put it in a `.js` file it doesn't work!

I could use button `onclick="window.open;"`like this:

```
<button id="download1" class="button2">BUTTON</button>
```

But this should work for different files and I want to use one `.js` for this, so I can change the `URL` later and it would work for all files.

Comment: did you wrap your .js in a document.ready function, or include it at the bottom of your page?

Comment: make sure you are loading script after html is loaded, add it before `</body>` tag or after your content.

Comment: Is the `.js` file referenced from a script tag?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code using the browser's built-in developer tools? I'm guessing that you're getting at least one error message that you haven't reported

Comment: Guys I am stupid asf*... I see that the code is between <head> Now it works, thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

1- include your js file in the bottom of the page

2- try this

```
document.getElementById('download1').addEventListener('click',function(){
            window.location.href="https://youtube.com";
        });
```